# How to get name of instance from class in for loop

Tags: python, oop, for-loop, instance

I have multiple instances from a class that I add to a list. I iterate through that list checking some conditions. With those conditions, I select certain objects from the list and add them to a new list. Because these objects come from a class, the contents of the new list are the memory allocations of the objects from the class. I wish to get the original name of the instance.

I honestly do not know why this is the way it is and I haven't found any answers that fix this, perhaps I'm making a mistake somewhere or I just don't know. Please post answers

```py
class Node():
    def __init__(self, y, x):
        self.y = y
        self.x = x
    def operation(self):
        return x**2

node1 = Node(2,2)
node2 = Node(3,3)

nodes = [node1, node2]

for node in nodes:
    good_nodes = []
    if ##CONDITIONS##:
        ##select certain nodes##
    else:
        good_nodes.append(##selected_nodes##, for example : node1)

print(good_nodes)
```

What is returned:
`[<__main__.Node object at 0x7fe608b27668>]`

What I want to be returned (a list):
`[node1,node2,etc]`

Comment: What do you mean by original name? Do you want the name of the variable that you used?

Comment: The list items **are** your objects. The fact that you gave these objects some names is irrelevant, the objects don't know about it, neither does the list, so these names will not appear anywhere when you print the textual representation of the list.

Comment: You could maybe make use of `locals()`, try printing it to see what it contains. But I have no idea why you need to do this.

Comment: @Thierry Lathuille, This means I have to change to code entirely to get what I want

Answer (score 0):

Names are associated with values. A value has no knowledge of the names that refer to it. This means that you cannot get a variable name from a value.

If you want to print out something that identifies the node in a meaningful way, then you can override `__str__()`. For example:

```
class Node:
    # existing code
    def __str__(self):
        return '(' + str(self.x) + ', ' + str(self.y) + ')'
```

If you want each node to have a name, then you have to add it yourself:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, y, x, name):
        self.y = y
        self.x = x
        self.name = name
```

To print this out, you will have to modify the `__str__()` function in my first example.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice if you want to identify the instances of Node by a name later is to add a name attribute to the object.  Using variable names is generally not a good idea because what they refer to can change.

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, name, y, x):
        self.name = name
        self.y = y
        self.x = x
    def operation(self):
        return x**2
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

node1 = Node('node1', 2, 2)
node2 = Node('node2', 2, 2)

In [0]: print([node1,node2])
Out [0]: 
    [node1, node2]
```

Answer (score -1):

You seem to be wanting to access the names of variables referencing objects in one part of the code, in a completely different part of the code. Unfortunately, that's not how Python works.

The names `node1` and `node2` are only meaningful in that block of code, and cannot be reverse-engineered if you have a reference to the same object in a different block of code.  That would cause problems if two blocks of code had different names for the same object. Which one is the "real" one? If you want them to have a canonical name, you will have to give them one, like the other answers are suggesting.

I'd also like to point out that you have a bug in your code:

```
...
for node in nodes:
    good_nodes = [] ## BUG HERE ##
    if ##CONDITIONS##:
        ##select certain nodes##
    else:
        good_nodes.append(##selected_nodes##, for example : node1)
...
```

`good_nodes` is being overwritten every loop here, so you will only print the last "good node". You need to move the line outside the loop:

```
...
nodes = [node1, node2]

good_nodes = [] # Much better!
for node in nodes:
    if ##CONDITIONS##:
        ##select certain nodes##
    else:
        good_nodes.append(##selected_nodes##, for example : node1)

print(good_nodes)
```